# maxima's ode solver

Tags: sage, ode, maxima

I downloaded and installed sage because I needed an ODE solver.I think that Maxima is relatively restricted in that part as it doesn't seem to solve almost basic ODEs.I appreciate all the effort that's been put into that project but I really could use a stronger solver.Are there any other free alternatives?What about the Axiom packages?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a keen Maxima user, I'm not sure I can help you with finding a different solver. But maybe Maxima can do what you need. You could always try specifying more clearly what you're trying to do either here or (more likely to be successful) try asking a question at Maxima's [mailing list](http://www.math.utexas.edu/mailman/listinfo/maxima).